# Flask server running Bokeh app: how to access plots from a script generated by server_document() function

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, bokeh, html-templates

I've been using Bokeh to plot a large database and Flask to serve the app on localhost. The summarized code looks like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

def make_doc(doc):

    def plot_time():
        p = figure(plot_height=400, plot_width=1000, tools="xpan,box_zoom,xwheel_zoom,reset,save", 
            x_axis_type="datetime", background_fill_color="#efefef",outline_line_color="#000000")       
        for us,color in zip(lista_plots,colors):
            p.line(x="Instant", y=us, source=source, name=us, line_color=color, line_width=1, legend=us.title())                
        return p

    def plot_time_aux(): 
        p = figure(plot_height=115, plot_width=1000, x_axis_type="datetime", y_axis_type=None, tools="",  background_fill_color="#efefef")
        for us in list_plots:
            p.line(x="Instant", y=us, source=source, name=us, line_color="gray", alpha=0.55)   
        return p

p1 = plot_time()
p2 = plot_time_aux()
doc.add_root(p1)
doc.add_root(p2)
doc.title = "Time Plot"

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])

def bkapp_page():
    script = server_document('http://localhost:5006/bkapp')
    return render_template("index.html", script=script)

def bk_worker():
    server = Server({'/bkapp': make_doc}, io_loop=IOLoop(), allow_websocket_origin=["localhost:{}".format(port)])
    server.start()
    server.io_loop.start()

from threading import Thread
Thread(target=bk_worker).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Opening single process Flask app with embedded Bokeh application on http://localhost:{}/'.format(port))
    webbrowser.open_new("http://localhost:{}/".format(port))
    app.run(port=port, debug=False)
```

The code runs just fine, but when it comes to access p1 and p2 to insert it in the custom divs in the Jinja2 html template, I can't figure out how. The html template looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Time Plots</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for root in script.roots %}
        <div>{{ embed(root) }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    {{ script | safe }}
</body>
</html>
```

As it is, the script plots p1 and p2 one after the other, and just ignores the Jinja2 **for** loop (problably because the variables I'm referencing in the template don't exist...). However, I'd like to pass each plot (p1 and p2) as arguments in the render_template() funtion, so that I could be free to put them at any place on the html template, but I don't have a clue how.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will provide an outline of how to implement multiple plots:

1. Create a separate Bokeh application for each plot. Refer `modify_doc` at the [example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/examples/howto/server_embed/flask_embed.py#L16)

   ```
   def change_doc1():
     # code to define how plot 1 should behave

   def change_doc2():
     # code to define how plot 2 should behave
   ```
2. Initialize the Bokeh Server with multiple applications instead of a single application

   ```
   def bk_worker():
       plots = { "/plot1": change_doc1, "/plot2": change_doc2 }
       server = Server(plots, io_loop=IOLoop(), allow_websocket_origin=["localhost:{}".format(port)])
       server.start()
       server.io_loop.start()
   ```
3. Get the scrtips separately in the Flask route and send them to the template.

   ```
   @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
   def bkapp_page():
       script1 = server_document('http://localhost:5006/plot1')
       script2 = server_document('http://localhost:5006/plot2')
       return render_template("embed.html", script1=script1, script2=script2)
   ```
4. Use the scripts in the template seperately and position it where ever you want to in the HTML

   ```
   <!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Time Plots</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="plot1">
       {{ script1 | safe }}
     </div>
     <div id="plot2">
       {{ script2 | safe }}
     </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: Hey thanks!! I'll test that. My only concern now about having separate scripts is that in my case the plots are linked and share data between them. Do you think it's possible to share `x_range()` and data with widgets in this form? 
Since I made the question I managed to access the roots in the Bokeh Document using `bokeh serve` instead of calling the server programmatically, as suggested in [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#userguide-embed-apps)